# Python: Value of Dictionary as List - Initiate

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary where the value is a list. Now with every new incoming key I want to start a new list.
If I simply try to append to the dictionary key value it shows an error, since the value is not yet declared a list, and I can't do this at the beginning since I don't know how many keys I'll have.
For example (Note that for `MyDict` `keyList` is variable, something not previously known)

```
keyList = [['a',1,2],['b',3,4]]
MyDict={}
for key in keyList:
    MyDict[key[0]].append(key[1:])
```

What I want to create is:

```
MyDict={'a': [[1, 2]], 'b': [[3, 4]]}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yeah there is. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: use defaultdict , `MyDict=defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdefault`.

Instead of `MyDict[key[0]].append(key[1:])`

Try using `MyDict.setdefault(key[0],[]).append(key[1:])`

So when you are trying to append value, if the list doesn't exist it will make a default list and then append value to it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `defaultdict`, which is supplied with Python exactly for this purpose:

```
keyList = [['a',1,2],['b',3,4]]
MyDict=defaultdict(list)
for key in keyList:
    MyDict[key[0]].append(key[1:])

print(MyDict)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [[3, 4]], 'a': [[1, 2]]})
```

`defaultdict` gets in its constructor a function which is called without arguments to create default elements. `list` without arguments creates an empty list.

`defaultdict` behaves in all other ways like a normal dictionary.
If, nevertheless, in the end you want a simple dict, then convert it using `dict`:

```
print(dict(MyDict))
```

gives

```
{'b': [[3, 4]], 'a': [[1, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collections.defaultdict. Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])
d['key'].append('value to be add in list')
```

Sidenote: Defaultdict takes a callable argument, which means that you can also create your dict in this way:

```
defaultdict(list)
```